# Is doing this: var[property] more resource intensive than var.property?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, properties

I'm about to refactor a long algorithm so it can be adapted to any property instead of a fixed one.

So, instead of having var.x I would have var[property], where property can be x, y, alpha, etc.

But, a question appeared, performance wise, does it present an impact?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relative terms yes it's slower, whether that matters depends on deep specifics of your application and its usage patterns.

Comment: I see, I'm developing this app for mobile, do you have any numbers so I can have in mind if this work is worth doing?. Thanks.

Comment: @Artemix before we waste any time, how often in your application would you need to do these property reads? Like if the algorithm performs now 50 static reads but would perform 50 dynamic reads with the refactoring, and you call the algorithm 50 times per second, that would be 2500 times per second (And in this example the numbers are so low that you would be wasting your time thinking about this).

Comment: The idea is to use it to animate visual components, so, whenever that happens, I will use them in an EnterFrame event.

Comment: @Artemix Then don't worry about it. You will enter frame maybe 60 per second maximum, right?

Comment: Yeah, 60 fps would be the maximum rate. However, I use the variables several times, let say, I read/write them 20 times per frame.

Comment: @Artemix Yeah, forget about it. Come back when you need to do 100 000 reads in 16 milliseconds :P

Comment: Just to throw some actual numbers into the discussion, the difference is in the microsecond range. I just ran some tests on the look ups and I could not register a difference using `getTimer()` or `Date.time` which are accurate to the millisecond. The object I tried it on had 100,000 properties and both lookups took less than a ms to do each. Hell, looking up all 100,000 using `['name']` took less than a frame to complete. The times are so minuscule, it will not make a difference in most cases.

Comment: @JoshJanusch it easily makes a difference in games and physics simulations for example but in average applications yeah :P btw `['name']` is same as `.name` the problem is when `[variable]` because it has dynamic semantics

Comment: @Esailija Even then, I'm not sure it will make a difference. Doing that many lookups in under a frame is going to cause issues no matter what method you use because the difference is too small to make that much a difference, at least at 100,000. You might notice a difference if you did 10, 100, or even 1000x more than that, but if you are doing that many lookups in a single frame, there might be better ways to do what you're doing.